# zookeeper and supervisor do not work well togeather

Tags: apache-zookeeper, supervisord

Below is my supervisord.conf file.  One would think that it would start zookeeper but it does not.

ZK works manually if I run sh /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground

```
# -*- conf -*-

[include]
files = *.supervisor

[supervisord]
pidfile = /var/run/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisord.sock ; use a unix:// URL for a unix socket

[unix_http_server]
file = /var/run/supervisord.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface


[program:zookeeper]
command= sh /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
process_name=%(program_name)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/zookeeper.log
stopsignal=KILL
#stopasgroup = true
#killasgroup = true
#stdout_logfile = /tmp/zookeeper.out
#stderr_logfile = /tmp/zookeeper.err
pidfile = /var/run/zookeeper.pid


[group:zookeeper_server]
programs=zookeeper
```

Comment: you can redirect both stdout and stderr to /var/log/zookeeper.log, command= sh /var/chef/cache/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground >> /var/log/zookeeper.log 2>&1 .

Comment: Hello @Tampa, how was your journey with zookeeper and supervisord ? I am looking for a supervisory process for zookeeper, and i would like to know if supervisord is the way to go, although on the zookeeper website, it mentions daemontools.

Answer (score 0):

Use the explicit command without calling the shell in the command for instance:

```
command=/opt/java/bin/java -Dzookeeper.log.dir="." -cp "/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.2.2.Final.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../conf:"  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "/home/app/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg"
```

With java in /opt/java/ and zookeeper in /home/app/zookeeper

To find it you can launch the shell and copy-paste the command line.

It seems supervisor has sometimes troubles with shell scripts and python scripts depending on os / vm etc. I didn't find the reason yet.

But if you use a standalone command it works pretty well.

I execute zookeeper as foreground process in supervisord, disable rolling logs in zookeeper log4j configuration (only console) and use supervisord rotation. It does the job.